# Как лучше хранить Routing в Laravel?

Tags: laravel, маршрутизация

Предполагается, что будут генерироваться новые пути автоматически. Каждый раз генерить код не вариант. MySQL XML LiteSQL возможно какой-то еще вариант?

Comment: Вы, в принципе, знакомы с роутингом в Laravel? `Предполагается, что будут генерироваться новые пути автоматически.` подробней опишите

Comment: Возможно вы говорите о /user и т.д. я больше имел ввиду, поддомены. например есть site1 2.site1 и т.д. Все что я видел это стандартные пути. Или скажем раздел news/ пользователь хочет добавить свой раздел blogs summerBlog
т.е. news--
                ----blogs
                ----summerBlog
т.е. система где на основе одного компонента можно создать любой раздел в любом месте

Comment: Напр. пакет есть [tenancy for Laravel](https://github.com/archtechx/tenancy) для поддоменов или самому писать надо обработку. А касательно примера с созданием разделов то всё конечно в базе должно храниться, а роут один будет парсить всё нужно